# Iterating through array to find occurrences of value

Tags: arrays, for-loop, swift, nsarray

I have been trying to iterate through an array to check how many times two particular values occur. I came up with this code:

```
    var paymentNum = 0
    var creditNum = 0
    for index in images {
        if images.objectAtIndex(index) == 0 {
            paymentNum = paymentNum + 1
        } else {
            creditNum = creditNum + 1
        }
        }
```

This doesn't seem to work though. I just get the error 'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'Int'.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is images an array of objects with multiple properties?

Comment: It just contains either 1s or 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making some pretty huge assumptions because you don't have much detail about what's going on.
I'm assuming that images is an NSArray. NSArray in Objective-C translates into an [AnyObject] in swift.
When you have a for-each style loop like this

```
for value in array
{}
```

the loop will iterate through each value in the array. Value is the actual object in the array, not a counter as in a `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` style loop

So what you're probably really expecting to do is

```
for item in images {
    if item == 0 {
        paymentNum++
    } else {
        creditNum++
    }
}
```

you also might need to cast the loop from an `[AnyObject]` to an `[Int]` like this

```
let tmp = images as [Int]
for item in tmp
{...}
```

or, cast the value pulled out of the array like this

```
for item in images {
    if (item as Int) == 0 {
        paymentNum++
    } else {
        creditNum++
    }
}
```

But the former is probably preferable

Answer (score 1):

paste ina playground:

```
import Foundation

let images = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
var paymentNum = 0
var creditNum = 0
for item in images {
    println(item)
    if item == 0 {
        paymentNum = paymentNum + 1

    } else {
        creditNum = creditNum + 1
    }
}

println(paymentNum) //4
println(creditNum) //6
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a more compact way of achieving that, in just 2 lines of code.
It makes the assumption that an array element it's a credit if its value is 1, otherwise is 0.

That said, if you sum up all elements of array, you obtain the number of credits - the number of payments is the array size minus the number of credits.

To sum all elements of the array, the simplest way is using the `reduce` method (more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW46))

```
var creditNum = images.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + $1 } )
var paymentNum = images.count - creditNum
```

If using values different than 0 or 1 to identify credits and payments, then the calculation can be modified to check for explicit values as follows:

```
var creditNum = images.reduce(0, combine: { $0 + ($1 == 1 ? 1 : 0) } )
```

Here it takes the previous count ($0) and add either 1 or 0, depending whether the element array ($1) is equal to 1 or not.